# Error-Subscript is invalid because list is empty

Tags: apex

I am trying to show all records and their relationship records but i am getting this error.
Subscript is invalid because list is empty

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="Job_Posting__c" extensions="PopulatedHistoryCtrl" >

<apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock title="Child with all Parents">

        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!conlist}" var="c">
            <apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.AccountID}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.ChildContacts__r[0].Contact__c  }"/>






        </apex:pageblockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>


</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class PopulatedHistoryCtrl {


    //public List<Job_Posting__c>  joblist{get;set;} 
    public List<Contact> conlist{get;set;}

    public PopulatedHistoryCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

      //  emplist=new List<Employment_Website__c>();
       // poslist=new List<Position__c>();
        conlist=new List<Contact>();

        conlist=[select id,Name,AccountId,(select Contact__c  from ChildContacts__r) from Contact];




    }

}
```

Comment: check whether your conlist is getting populated or not.

Comment: @Anu:List is getting populated but when i am trying to involve <apex:column value="{!c.ChildContacts__r[0].Contact__c  }"/> this line it is throwing me error  Subscript is invalid because list is empty

Comment: use it like this c.ChildContacts__r.Contact__c

Comment: @Anu: I didnt get your point.

Comment: post your conlist debug result. and try to change your c.ChildContacts__r[0].Contact__c to !c.ChildContacts__r.Contact__c

Comment: In debug it is showing Total 28 Records. And after showing that it is showing me error Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Contact__c'

Comment: Did you try this  c.ChildContacts__r[0].Contact__c to !c.ChildContacts__r.Contact__c

Comment: Yes i tried this but it is giving me error "Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Contact__c' 
"

Answer (score 2):

Hello Shantanu actually you can only show only one child record name in your table using `c.ChildContacts__r[0].Contact__c` it will show first related child record `contact__c` field. Reason for your error is some Parent are present in your Contact object without any child record. that's the reason for your error.

So make Sure there should not be any contact records without having child records.

Comment: Iam also getting the same error, my requirement is to display first child record only. How can i fix this error, please suggest me.